# WPF Vector Printing - Send DrawingGroup as Vector to printer

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector, printing, raster

I would like to use WPF to programmatically print. However, I need all the material to be sent to the printer in vector graphics and not raster graphics.

The main issue is, I cannot get WPF to print vector graphics, the prints always gets rasterized.

I use[SharpVectors](https://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/), which transforms an .svg file into am .xaml drawing group. And then insert that drawing group into an Image into a flowdocument, finally I send the flowdocument to print using an XPSDocumentWriter.

Blurry every time. I compare the print to the .svg file printed from adobe Illustrator. Night and day quality.

Is there any way to take a drawing group and always have it print as vector?

I am putting a bounty on this. You must submit the c# code necessary to send the following drawing group to the printer as vector graphics, this must be reproducible to get the bounty. Also, simply increasing the DPI after the image is rasterized does not qualify as an answer. No vector print - no bounty.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M6Yes83t08V0ZOOEp1Q3dEYjA/view?usp=sharing
[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M6Yes83t08V0ZOOEp1Q3dEYjA/view?usp=sharing)
[DrawingGroup xaml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M6Yes83t08V0ZOOEp1Q3dEYjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like this was already a problem 6 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286665/what-causes-wpf-printer-output-to-be-rasterized - so maybe you're better off using an svg-to-GDI library such as https://github.com/vvvv/SVG ?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in these libraries that will send an SVG as vector to print. They are all tools to help render on a display but not print. I think GDI is only raster graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can ! ;-)
I think you'd better forget the image and use a FixedDocument

First create a class, overriding OnRender :

```
public partial class MapDrawingElement : FrameworkElement
{
    public MapDrawingElement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        var res = Resources["drawingGroup1"] as DrawingGroup;
        if (res != null)
            drawingContext.DrawDrawing(res);
    }
}
```

The class has a drawingGroup1 Resource in its resource section :

```
<FrameworkElement x:Class="DemoFixedpageDocument.MapDrawingElement"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <DrawingGroup x:Key="drawingGroup1">
... here your xaml 16k lines ! ...
        </DrawingGroup>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
</FrameworkElement>
```

Instanciate a FixedDocument, and put the control with the map in a page :

```
public static class DocumentMaker
{
    public static FixedDocument GenerateFixedDocument()
    {
        FixedDocument fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
        PageContent pageContent1 = new PageContent();
        fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent1);
        FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
        // PageContent : some text or an object can be added
        ((IAddChild)pageContent1).AddChild(page1);

        MapDrawingElement elt = new MapDrawingElement();
        page1.Children.Add(elt);
        return fixedDocument;
    }
}
```

Then you can print :

```
    PrintDocumentImageableArea imageArea = null;
    XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(ref imageArea);
    if (xpsdw != null)
    {
        xpsdw.Write(DocumentMaker.GenerateFixedDocument());
    }
```

You can also  print preview or send to an XPS file.

See the working demo in the link :

http://1drv.ms/1RefeuJ

Regards